# Borel sigma algebra, generated by borel functions, representation of a point

Tags: general-topology

Please let me ask a question about $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $E$ be a Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{B}(E)$ denotes its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of $\mathcal{B}(E)$-measurable function. For a subset $Y \subset E$, $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$ equipped with the trace topology inherited from $E$. (i.e. $\mathcal{B}(Y)=Y \cap \mathcal{B}(E) $)

**Assumption**:
There exists a subset $N\subset E$ such that $ \mathcal{B}(E \backslash N) \subset \sigma\{ u_{n}\,|\,n\in \mathbb{N} \}$

For all $ z \in E \backslash N $, we define
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{U}_{z}&:=\left\{ \begin{array}{c|l}
\{u_{n_{1}}\geq a_{1} \},  & n_{1} \in \mathbb{N}, a_{1} \in \mathbb{Q} \,{\rm s.t.} u_{n_{1}}(z)\geq a_{1} \\
\{ u_{n_{2}}< a_{2} \} & n_{2} \in \mathbb{N}, a_{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \,{\rm s.t.} u_{n_{2}}(z)< a_{2}
\end{array} \right\}, \,A_{z}:=\bigcap_{U \in \mathcal{U_{z}}}U
\end{eqnarray*}

We can see $\displaystyle A_{z} \in \mathcal{B}(E)$, $\displaystyle z \in  A_{z} \cap (E \backslash N) $, $\displaystyle   A_{z} \cap (E\backslash N) \in \mathcal{B}(E \backslash N) $.

**Question**:

Can we show $\displaystyle \{z\} =A_{z} \cap (E\backslash N) $ ?

**Attempt**:

I think it is enough to show that $\displaystyle A_{z} \cap (E \backslash N)$ is the smallest set in $\mathcal{B}(E \backslash N)$ containing $z$.

Fix $B \in \mathcal{B}(E \backslash N)$ s.t. $z \in B$.

We can assume $B=B_{1} \cap (E \backslash N)$, $B_{1} \in \mathcal{B}(E)$.
If $B_{1} \in \mathcal{U}_{z}(\subset \mathcal{B}(E))$,
it is obvious that  $\displaystyle A_{z}  \subset B_{1} $. Hence  $\displaystyle A_{z} \cap (E \backslash N) \subset B$. But I can't deal with the case $A_{1} \in \mathcal{B}(E), A_{1} \notin \mathcal{U}_{z} $. I don't know how to the proper way to use **Assumption**. What can we know from $B \in \sigma\{ u_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ ?

Thank you in advance.